# How to insert database mysql. Solve?

Tags: mysql, sql, pymysql, biopython

How can I insert the file data into the table mysql?

code:

```
import pymysql.cursors
import pymysql as MySQLdb
import pymysql
from Bio import SeqIO

try:
    conexao = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="xxx",db="db_teste")
    print("conectado")
    print(conexao)
except:
    print("Não conectado")


for item in SeqIO.parse('seqteste.txt', 'fasta'):
    dados = print('>{}\t{}'.format(str(item.description).replace('|', '\t'), item.seq), )
    with conexao:
         with conexao.cursor() as cursor:
            sql =  "INSERT INTO `tabelateste` (`id`, `id_name`, `host`, `organism`, `seq`) VALUES(1, %s, %s, %s,%s, %s)"
            cursor.execute(sql, (dados, dados, dados, dados, dados,))
            conexao.commit()
```

Erros:

```
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (1136, "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1")
```

our:

```
sql =  "INSERT INTO `tabelateste` (`id`, `id_name`, `host`, `organism`, `seq`) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s,%s, %s)"
            cursor.execute(sql, (dados, dados, dados, dados, dados))
            conexao.commit()

error:

    line 125, in mogrify
        query = query % self._escape_args(args, conn)
    TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

How to solve this error and be able to insert the data in the mysqldb table?

myseq:

```
>gb:KX262887|Organism:Zika virus|Strain Name:103451|Segment:null|Subtype:Asian|Host:Human
GTTGTTGATCTGTGTGAATCAGACTGCGACAGTTCGAGTTTGAAGCGAAAGCTAGCAACAGTATCAACAG
GTTTTATTTTGGATTTGGAAACGAGAGTTTCTGGTCATGAAAAACCCAAAAAAGAAATCCGGAGGATTCC

>gb:KX262887|Organism:Zika virus|Strain Name:103451|Segment:null|Subtype:Asian|Host:Human
    GTTGTTGATCTGTGTGAATCAGACTGCGACAGTTCGAGTTTGAAGCGAAAGCTAGCAACAGTATCAACAG
    GTTTTATTTTGGATTTGGAAACGAGAGTTTCTGGTCATGAAAAACCCAAAAAAGAAATCCGGAGGATTCC

>gb:KX262887|Organism:Zika virus|Strain Name:103451|Segment:null|Subtype:Asian|Host:Human
    GTTGTTGATCTGTGTGAATCAGACTGCGACAGTTCGAGTTTGAAGCGAAAGCTAGCAACAGTATCAACAG
    GTTTTATTTTGGATTTGGAAACGAGAGTTTCTGGTCATGAAAAACCCAAAAAAGAAATCCGGAGGATTCC
```

expected exit Output:

mysqldb

```
id  id_name            host        organism         seq
1   gb:KX262887        Human       Zika Virus       aatgtgttt
```

Solve?

Comment: Why are you always inserting with the same ID value? That should be either `AUTO_INCREMENT`, in which case it's omitted from the insert list, or generated in advance.

Comment: Hint: You have 1 fixed value + 5 placeholders = 6, but only 5 columns specified. Remember, each `%s` should have a corresponding value *and* column.

Comment: I would like to insert the data as it is printed

column1
Human

column2
Dengue

...
 id_name host organism seq
1 gb: KX262887 Human Zika Virus aatgtgttt

But, I can't solve the error

Comment: what does:  '' mysql > SHOW TABLES; ''  shows for your database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must carefully match the columns, the placeholders, and the values so that there is an *identical* number of each:

```py
sql =  "INSERT INTO `tabelateste` (`id`, `id_name`, `host`, `organism`, `seq`) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
            cursor.execute(sql, (dados, dados, dados, dados, dados))
            conexao.commit()
```

Note how there's 5 columns specified, 5 placeholders, and 5 binds in the tuple now. You had an extra `%s`.

Conceptually what you want to do is:

```
(column_name, ...) <-- Columns specified
     |
     v
(   %s      , ... ) <-- Placeholders specified
     |
     v
(bind_value , ... ) <-- Binding on execute()
```

Note that these must correlate 1:1:1 *exactly*. Any mismatches will result in errors like you've seen.

Comment: I tried to change the number of columns and gave a new error ...
I shared the script below   TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: If you're getting a whole new problem it may be worth opening up a new question with that specific issue. Quite often one thing leads to another, that's fine. Accept this answer if it helped you get closer to your goal, or if another helps.

Comment: @tadman isnt the error in here: cursor.execute(sql, (dados, dados, dados, dados, dados,) being how dados is defined :  dados = print('>{}\t{}'.format(str(item.description).replace('|', '\t'), item.seq), ) ?

Comment: @pippo1980 That's likely another issue as I don't think `print` returns anything useful.

Comment: @tadman Is he/she parsing as fasta things should be parsed as genbank files ? I am not in the field is the input showed above good genbank format ?

Comment: @tadman ok got it dados should be a list where dados[4] can be item.seq parsing fasta file with seqIO.parse while dados[1] to [3] need to be extracted from item.description and dados[0] should be just the number of item in the file. Am I right ? My regex is null so can't advance more

Answer (score 0):

change :

```
for item in SeqIO.parse('seqteste.txt', 'fasta'):
    dados = print('>{}\t{}'.format(str(item.description).replace('|', '\t'), item.seq), )
```

into

```
import re

cnt = 0
for item in SeqIO.parse('seqteste.txt', 'fasta'):
    cnt += 1
    s=(str((item.description).strip('')))
    pattern_id = "(.*?)\|Organism"
    pattern_host = "Host:(.*.)"
    pattern_org = "Organism:(.*?)\|Strain"
    ids= re.search(pattern_id, s).group(1)
    host = re.search(pattern_host, s).group(1)
    org = re.search(pattern_org, s).group(1)
    dados = [str(cnt), ids ,host , org   ,str(item.seq)]
```

and :

```
 cursor.execute(sql, (dados, dados, dados, dados, dados))
```

with:

```
cursor.execute(sql, (dados[0] , dados[1] ,dados[2] ,dados[3] ,dados[4]))
```

let me know how it behaves, I dont have your database and can't test my code